# How to check One signal Player ids are valid or invalid in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification, onesignal

The problem is when I'm sending push notification using [one-signal documentation's nodejs code](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#send-based-on-filterstags---create-notification),

I've array of player ids : `['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5']`

It only send to first 2 player ids or device token then the 3rd token/player id is invalid so it won't send notification to other player ids which are after 3rd player id in the array .

It gives me error and response as below :

```
{
   "id":"17236233-2a86-4e13-a6c4-0f0a51ba053a",
   "recipients":2,
   "external_id":null,
   "errors":{
      "invalid_player_ids":[
         "id3",
         "id5"
      ]
   }
}
```

#### Expectation :

I want to check invalid player ids and then remove from array,
So i can send push notification to only valid player ids.

#### Thank you so much for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Self answering for the solution that worked for me as well it will work for other developers and help them.

So i researched for checking PlayerId is valid or not on [One-signal documentation View Device](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/view-device).

And below is my code to check playerId is valid or not, and also the playerId is now exist on my One-signal Users. then I'm doing these steps :

1. If it's not valid/exist, so I'm simply removing it from my database so it won't cause any error in future when sending push.
2. Making final `validDevices` array to only send push notification to valid devices, so it won't return any error.

#### function to sendNotification

```
const sendPushNotificationToUser = async (devices) => {
  let validDevices = [];
  console.log(`All devices-->`, devices);
  for (let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    let isValid = await removeInvalidPlayerIds(devices[i]);
    if (isValid) {
      validDevices.push(devices[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(`Valid devices-->`, validDevices);

  if (validDevices.length > 0) {
    //code for send notification
  }
};
```

#### Removing Invalid/non-exist playerIds

```
const removeInvalidPlayerIds = async (device) => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        host: "onesignal.com",
      },
    };
    const onesignalURL = `https://104.18.226.52:443/api/v1/`,
      url = `${onesignalURL}players/${device}?app_id=${process.env.ONESIGNAL_APPID}`;
    let response = await axios.get(url, config);
    response = response.data;
    if (response && response.invalid_identifier == true) {
      // removing token and return false
      await UserDeviceService.deleteUserDeviceWithoutUserId(device);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      let { data } = error.response;
      // The request was made
      // the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx

      if (data.hasOwnProperty("errors")) {
        // removing token and return false
        await UserDeviceService.deleteUserDeviceWithoutUserId(device);
        return false;
      }
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.log("error.request");
    } else {
      console.log("Error", error.message);
    }
  }
};
```